# Angular2: ngOnit not being called

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Using angular 2.0.0-rc.4 and router 3.0.0-beta.2. When I navigate to a route or do a fresh reload, ngOnInit is not called. If I click an anchor tag matching the current route then ngOnInit is called. What am I doing wrong?

profile-routes.ts

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';
import { ProfileFormComponent } from './profile-form.component';

export const ProfileRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ProfileFormComponent             
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

profile-component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfileFormComponent } from './profile-form.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'profile',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ProfileComponent {

}
```

profile-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'profile-form',
    templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile-form.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] 
})

export class ProfileFormComponent implements OnInit {           

    ngOnInit() {        
        console.log('Onit'); //this isn't called
    }

}
```

Comment: Any errors that you are getting?

Comment: What browsers did you test with?

Comment: The issue happens in Firefox and Chrome. No errors shown in firebug.